# scatter plot for fisher iris

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I want to create a visualization with scatterplots of each pair of features in the Iris dataset - sepal width,sepal length,petal width, petal length. Also I need to define a class label to show which type of iris each one is (Setosa, Versicolor and Virginica).

I am new to Matlab, and do not know how to make such scatterplots. Could you please help me?

Thnks in advance

Comment: see [scatter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html). Keep one member out of a pair in `X` and the other one in `Y`. To distinguish between different class, plot different sets of instances with different colors (use `hold on` while plotting). Most importantly, show your code, then we will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have the Statistics Toolbox, you should use `gscatter` for grouped data.

For each pair of data you will need to call`gscatter(x,y,group)` - you can use additional inputs to control exactly how the data is plotted (colors, legend, etc.) - see the help file.

For the `fisheriris` data set, your `x` and `y` are the two measurements you're comparing (from `meas`), and the group labels are in `species`.